# Properly formatting the Table of Contents from a template

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to format the headings of the various sections (chapters) and subsections in my dissertation and the table of contents. I adapted a template that is available on the website of my department. I get exactly what is expected.

I would also appreciate an explanation for the following code at the end of the preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\catcode`\ =12\let\@nl@space= \catcode`\ =10
\newcount\@nl@rlevel
\newcount\@nl@llevel
\@nl@llevel=-1

\def\@nl{%
    \catcode`\ =12
    \global\@nl@rlevel=0
    \futurelet\@nl@store\@nl@%
}


\makeatother
```

By the way, this is not my dissertation. On a whim, I decided to post the code for the template with text on fairy tales.

Here is the main file.

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside]{book}

% packages
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

% these make top, right, bottom margins confirming to the requirements

\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.0in,%
left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
footskip=.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% small stuff
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{footnote}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black},urlcolor={black}}

\usepackage{microtype}
% \usepackage{showkeys}
% uncomment this when editing cross-references
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

% this makes the chapters start with a 2" margin
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@makechapterhead[1]{%
    \vspace*{0.75in}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
}}
\renewcommand*\@makeschapterhead[1]{%
    \vspace*{0.75in}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
        \normalfont
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
}}
\makeatother

% theorem style


\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{theorem}[subsection]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[subsection]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[subsection]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[subsection]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[subsection]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{principle}[subsection]{Principle}
\newtheorem{claim}[subsection]{Claim}
%\newtheorem*{main-theorem-1}{Main Theorem}
%\newtheorem*{nil-to-local-repeat}{Proposition \ref{nil-to-local}}
%\newtheorem*{restate-tech-thm}{Theorem \ref{mainthm-tech}}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{definition}[subsection]{Definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\theoremstyle{remark}

\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{examples}{Examples}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{remarks}{Remarks}

%I prefer slanted leq and geq symbols
\renewcommand{\leq}{\leqslant}
\renewcommand{\geq}{\geqslant}

%This is all so I could finish a proof with an equation if need be.
\newsavebox{\proofbox}
\savebox{\proofbox}{\begin{picture}(7,7)%
    \put(0,0){\framebox(7,7){}}\end{picture}}
\def\boxeq{\tag*{\usebox{\proofbox}}}



%\def\proof{\noindent\textit{Proof. }}
\def\endproof{\hfill{\usebox{\proofbox}}}




\parindent 0mm
\parskip   5mm % this should make \ni and  obsolete, hopefully
%\newenvironment{proof}{\noindent {\bf Proof} }{\endprf\par}
\def \endprf{\hfill  {\vrule height6pt width6pt depth0pt}\medskip}



\makeatletter
\catcode`\ =12\let\@nl@space= \catcode`\ =10
\newcount\@nl@rlevel
\newcount\@nl@llevel
\@nl@llevel=-1

\def\@nl{%
    \catcode`\ =12
    \global\@nl@rlevel=0
    \futurelet\@nl@store\@nl@%
}


\makeatother
%------------------------------------------------




% doesn't count introduction when numbering theorems, etc.
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

% makes page numbers appear
\pagestyle{plain}


\begin{document}

% makes the page numbers roman numerals, doesn't count
% these pages in the table of contents
\frontmatter

\thispagestyle{empty}

\vbox to 1truein{}

\centerline{Fairy Tales throughout History}



\vskip 200pt

\centerline{BY}
\vskip 10pt

\centerline{A Storyteller}
\vskip 10pt

\centerline{BA, Bard College}
\centerline{MA, Columbia University}

\vskip 215pt

\centerline{DISSERTATION}
\vskip 10pt

\centerline{Submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for}
\centerline{the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in English}
\centerline{in the Graduate School of}
\centerline{Columbia University}


\newpage


\thispagestyle{empty}

\vbox to 9.0truein{}

\centerline{\copyright\ Copyright by A Storyteller 2023}

\

\centerline{All Rights Reserved}

\newpage



\chapter*{Abstract}
\begin{doublespace}
Fairy tales' rich, imaginative stories for children~---~involving fantastical creatures and exotic places~---~offer far more than entertainment and happily-ever-after endings. They furnish children with a landscape for critical thinking skills and a context in which children can evaluate their own emotions and decision making.
\end{doublespace}


\newpage

\chapter*{Dedication}
\bigskip

\centerline{Dedicated to the Grimm Brothers and Hans Christian Anderson}

\newpage

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I wish to thank Walt Disney for animating various fairy tales in full color.


\newpage

\tableofcontents

% Changes page numbers to regular numbers, resets the counter
\mainmatter

%This gives 10pt font with 20pt spacing, text from here should be double spaced
\fontsize{10}{20pt} \selectfont

% \include puts in the .tex file with the given name
% make sure that these files don't have any preamble material

\begin{doublespacing}
    
\include{introduction_February_9}

\include{chapter_1_February_9}


\include{chapter_2_February_9}


\include{chapter_3_February_9}


\include{conclusion_February_9}


\end{doublespacing}

% add a new chapter without a chapter # for the references
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[Southey 1837]{Southey}Robert Southey, \emph{The Doctor},  Longman, Rees, Orme, Brown, Green and Longman, London, England, 1837, pages 318-326

\end{thebibliography}



\end{document}
```

Here is the Introduction. The name of the file is "introduction_February_9".

```
%
%
%
% Introduction
%
%

%Make the Introduction a chapter without a number.
\chapter*{Introduction}

% and include it on the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}


We will look at various fairy tales and myths in civilizations throughout history!
```

Here is Chapter 1. The name of the file is "chapter_1_February_9".

```
%
%  Chapter 1
%
%
%
%
%
\chapter{Fairy Tales from Ancient Greece}
\label{ch1}
% the label lets you refer to the chapter by number later.





\section{Theogony: Clash of the Titans}
\label{s1.1}

Talk some more.

\subsection{Subsection Title}
\label{ss1.1.1}

Be specific.

% if you want a subsection, but with no number
\subsection*{Numberless Subsection}

% you have to manually add it to the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Numberless Subsection}
\label{ss1.1.2}

\section{Prometheus and the Theft of Fire}
\label{s1.2}

Talk it up.

% you can do the same with sections, just * them and add them to the contents if you want.



\section{Pandora’s Box}

Keep going


\section{The Abduction of Persephone by Hades}

Way to go!
```

Here is Chapter 2. The name of the file is "chapter_2_February_9".

```
%
%  Chapter 2
%
%
%
%
%
\chapter{Fairy Tales from Ancient Rome}
\label{ch2}
% the label lets you refer to the chapter by number later.

{\em Talk a little.} \cite{keyword1}

\section{Romulus and Remus}

{\em Pages of exposition.}

\section{Aeneas (by the poet Virgil)}

{\em Pages of exposition.}
\label{s2.1}

{\em Talk a lot.}

%\begin{thm}[Theorem 1 \cite{keyword2}]
\label{thm1}
%Stuff is important.
%\end{thm}

\section{Scaevola}

{\em Pages of exposition.}
\label{s2.2}

{\em Do it again.}

\section{The Legend of Lucretia}

{\em Pages of exposition.}


%Theorem~\ref{thm1} is really important.  Chapter~\ref{ch1} was awesome.
```

Here is Chapter 3. The name of the file is "chapter_3_February_9".

```
%
%  Chapter 3
%
%
%
%
%
\chapter{European Fairy Tales}
\label{ch3}
%This label lets you refer to the chapter by number later.

{\em A paragraph} \cite{keyword1}

\section{English Fairy Tales}

{\em Pages of exposition.}

\subsection{Cinderella}

{\em Talk a little}

\subsection{Beauty and the Beast}

{\em Talk a little}


\subsection{Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs}

{\em Talk a little}


\subsection{Jack and the Beanstalk}

{\em Talk a little}


\subsection{Sleeping Beauty}

{\em Talk a little}

\subsection{Puss in Boots}

{\em Talk a little}



%\begin{thm}[Theorem 1 \cite{keyword2}]
\label{thm1}
%Stuff is important.
%\end{thm}

\section{German}

{\em Pages of exposition.}


\subsection{Rapunzel}

{\em Talk a little}

\subsection{Little Red Riding Hood (retold by The Brothers Grimm)}
{\em Talk a little}


\subsection{Rumpelstiltskin}
{\em Talk a little}

\section{Norwegian}

{\em Pages of exposition.}


\subsection{East of the Sun and West of the Moon}
{\em Talk a little}

\subsection{The Boy with the Beer Keg}
{\em Talk a little}

\subsection{Legends from the Mill}
{\em Talk a little}

\subsection{An evening at the neighbors}
{\em Talk a little}
```

Here is the Conclusion. The name of the file is "conclusion_February_9".

```
%
%
%
%Conclusions
%
%
%Do not put a chapter number on this section.
\chapter*{Conclusions}

% but include it on the contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusions}

Draw some conclusions.
```

Comment: you have posted a lot of code but we can not run it as it  `\include` files not provided,  but if `Rumpelstiltskin` is a section heading which should appear in the table of contents, don't use a font change such as `\textbf` use a heading `\section`

Comment: presumably `Print your stuff here" is typeset,` is in the file `introduction.tex` that you have not shown here

Comment: @David Carlisle  I will update the post today.

Comment: don't you intend "We will look at various fairy tales and myths in various civilizations."  to be _in_ the Introduction? You should move _all_ such text out of your main file and put it in the files you are including

Comment: @David Carlisle  Yes, you are correct. I edited my post. Now, I am asking one question in my post.

Comment: Your example is still unreasoably large if you are asking about the introduction you can remove all the later chapters also you have no question!!!!  Yt our orginal version asked about "Print your stuff here"" but now you have just posted code with no question

Comment: @David Carlisle  In my original post, I did not know that the command `\include{introduction_February_9}` called a file from the same folder containing the current LaTeX file for compilation. Now, I am asking for an explanation for code in the preamble. "I would also appreciate an explanation for the following code at the end of the preamble."

Comment: so why have you posted dozens of  lines of unrelated code????  the bit of code you show with `\@nl@rlevel` does not do anything at all, it is just some weird undocumented definition of a command that is not used, just delete it.

Comment: @David Carlisle  I have deleted it from the preamble. Thanks for your explanation.